# Overlaying full screen with bottomNavigationBar set?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to have a fullscreen progress hud (spinner) that is really full screen. My current Scaffold looks like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async =>
          !await navigatorKeys[currentTab].currentState.maybePop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

        body:  ModalProgressHUD(child: buildTabs(context), inAsyncCall: _saving, color: Colors.grey, opacity: 0.5),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          currentTab: currentTab,
          onSelectTab: _selectTab,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

based on this tutorial (https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf). In the "body" I have a widget ("ModalProgressHUD" from https://pub.dev/packages/modal_progress_hud) which shall overlay the full screen, but the bottom navigation bar is excluded from the overlay.

How can I have with a bottom navigation bar still a fullscreen overlay widget displaying some "in progress" spinner?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: I have a similar problem with Scaffold and BottomNavigationBar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231337/flutter-materialpageroute-as-fullscreendialog-appears-underneath-bottomnavigatio

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing... right after posting I found it out. Just need to wrap the "WillPopScope" into the ModalProgressHud widget and that's it

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ModalProgressHUD(child: buildScaffoldWidget(context), inAsyncCall: _saving, color: Colors.grey, opacity: 0.5);
  }

  Widget buildScaffoldWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async =>
          !await navigatorKeys[currentTab].currentState.maybePop(),
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

        body:  buildTabs(context),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          currentTab: currentTab,
          onSelectTab: _selectTab,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```